# Convert JavaScript array of objects to JSON in r programming language

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I need to pass JSON object to a function in r programming. The following are the various examples of JavaScript objects that can be passed which needed to be converted to JSON in r

```
Example1 = [
  {name: "Orange", data: {"Tuesday": 3, "Friday": 4}, stack: "fruit"},
  {name: "Apple", data: {"Tuesday": 1, "Friday": 8}, stack: "fruit"},
  {name: "Cucumber", data: {"Tuesday": 3, "Friday": 4}, stack: "vegetable"},
  {name: "Carrot", data: {"Tuesday": 1, "Friday": 8}, stack: "vegetable"}
]

Example2 = [["Washington", "1789-04-29", "1797-03-03"], ["Adams", "1797-03-03", "1801-03-03"]]
```

I need help converting them into a JSON object in r using jsonlite package.

Comment: `jsonlite::parse_json('[["Washington", "1789-04-29", "1797-03-03"], ["Adams", "1797-03-03", "1801-03-03"]]')` ?

Comment: Thank you @margusl. But this code returns a list not a JSON object. I can get a JSON object using jsonlite::fromJSON() for this example but not Example1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+convert+to+json

Comment: Valid point regarding Example1. Though the `list`  is the most common structure for storing parsed JSON objects in R.  `jsonlite::fromJSON()`,  when called with default arguments,  attempts to simplify the list and ends up with a matrix in this case. But you are after a JSON string?

Comment: Yes. I am after JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a "true" JSON string, you can use the **jsonNormalize** package.

```r
library(jsonNormalize)

jsonNormalize(
  '[
  {name: "Orange", data: {"Tuesday": 3, "Friday": 4}, stack: "fruit"},
  {name: "Apple", data: {"Tuesday": 1, "Friday": 8}, stack: "fruit"},
  {name: "Cucumber", data: {"Tuesday": 3, "Friday": 4}, stack: "vegetable"},
  {name: "Carrot", data: {"Tuesday": 1, "Friday": 8}, stack: "vegetable"}
]', prettify = TRUE)
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Orange",
    "data": {
      "Tuesday": 3,
      "Friday": 4
    },
    "stack": "fruit"
  },
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "data": {
      "Tuesday": 1,
      "Friday": 8
    },
    "stack": "fruit"
  },
  {
    "name": "Cucumber",
    "data": {
      "Tuesday": 3,
      "Friday": 4
    },
    "stack": "vegetable"
  },
  {
    "name": "Carrot",
    "data": {
      "Tuesday": 1,
      "Friday": 8
    },
    "stack": "vegetable"
  }
]
```

The **jsonNormalize** package also provides a RStudio addin allowing to normalize a **json** file by pressing a button.

Comment: Thank you @Stephane for your answer. Your solution worked on the example given. I am hoping you could review this JS object: ln_series_data =  jsonNormalize::jsonNormalize('[
  {name: "Workout", data: {"2021-01-01": 3, "2021-01-02": 4}},
  {name: "Call parents", data: {"2021-01-01": 5, "2021-01-02": 3}}
]')
The function jsonNormalize() did not work on it as it gave an error. You help is well appreciated

Comment: @JustB Indeed. I'm working on it (I'm the author of the package).

Comment: @JustB It should be fixed now. To install: `remotes::install_github("stla/jsonNormalize")`. Please say me if that works.

Comment: After installation,  jsonNormalize::jsonNormalize(jsonlite::toJSON('[
+   {name: "Workout", data: {"2021-01-01": 3, "2021-01-02": 4}},
+   {name: "Call parents", data: {"2021-01-01": 5, "2021-01-02": 3}}
+ ]'))
Error in jsonNormalize::jsonNormalize(jsonlite::toJSON("[\n  {name: \"Workout\", data: {\"2021-01-01\": 3, \"2021-01-02\": 4}},\n  {name: \"Call parents\", data: {\"2021-01-01\": 5, \"2021-01-02\": 3}}\n]")) : 
  Error while trying to remove trailing commas: Unexpected identifier

Comment: @JustB I think you don't have to do `jsonlite::toJSON` here. This function is for converting a R object to a JSON string.

Comment: You are right @Stephane. It worked. 
js_data <- '[
  {name: "Apple", data: {"Tuesday": 3, "Friday": 4}, stack: "fruit"},
  {name: "Pear", data: {"Tuesday": 1, "Friday": 8}, stack: "fruit"},
  {name: "Carrot", data: {"Tuesday": 3, "Friday": 4}, stack: "vegetable"},
  {name: "Beet", data: {"Tuesday": 1, "Friday": 8}, stack: "vegetable"}
]'

jsonNormalize(js_data)
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Javascript code can be evaluated with `v8`, that code can include `JSON.stringify()`, but for a list of simple assignment expressions we can set `serialize` parameter for `$eval()` method and it will return JSON string:

```r
library(V8)
#> Using V8 engine 9.1.269.38
js <- c(
  ex1 = 'Example1 = [
  {name: "Orange", data: {"Tuesday": 3, "Friday": 4}, stack: "fruit"},
  {name: "Apple", data: {"Tuesday": 1, "Friday": 8}, stack: "fruit"},
  {name: "Cucumber", data: {"Tuesday": 3, "Friday": 4}, stack: "vegetable"},
  {name: "Carrot", data: {"Tuesday": 1, "Friday": 8}, stack: "vegetable"}
]',
  ex2 = 'Example2 = [["Washington", "1789-04-29", "1797-03-03"], ["Adams", "1797-03-03", "1801-03-03"]]'
)

ctx <- v8()
# evaluate and serialize js return object
json_1 <- ctx$eval(js[1], serialize = TRUE) 
jsonlite::validate(json_1)
#> [1] TRUE
json_1
#> [1] "[{\"name\":\"Orange\",\"data\":{\"Tuesday\":3,\"Friday\":4},\"stack\":\"fruit\"},{\"name\":\"Apple\",\"data\":{\"Tuesday\":1,\"Friday\":8},\"stack\":\"fruit\"},{\"name\":\"Cucumber\",\"data\":{\"Tuesday\":3,\"Friday\":4},\"stack\":\"vegetable\"},{\"name\":\"Carrot\",\"data\":{\"Tuesday\":1,\"Friday\":8},\"stack\":\"vegetable\"}]"

# or apply ctx$eval() on the the list of expressions
json_lst <- lapply(js, ctx$eval, serialize = TRUE)
str(json_lst)
#> List of 2
#>  $ ex1: chr "[{\"name\":\"Orange\",\"data\":{\"Tuesday\":3,\"Friday\":4},\"stack\":\"fruit\"},{\"name\":\"Apple\",\"data\":{"| __truncated__
#>  $ ex2: chr "[[\"Washington\",\"1789-04-29\",\"1797-03-03\"],[\"Adams\",\"1797-03-03\",\"1801-03-03\"]]"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @margusl. Your answer hear has exposed me more to the understanding of JavaScript in R and the v8 package. I am using in my project as well. Thank you